# How to acces the src folder in jar app?

Tags: java

I'm making a jar application wich needs to acces files that are located in the src folder but when the app is compiled it uses the build directory instead of src.

The code to acces the files is this:

```
path="/Jinc/Sounds/"+folder+"/"+Integer.toString(voice)+".wav";
```

And it's the same for other types:

```
ConfigurationManager cm = new ConfigurationManager("src/clases/SpeechToText.config.xml");
```

The code sends this exception for the first one:

```
nullpointerexception
```

And a FileNotFoundexception for the second line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, don't.  Instead, you wan to use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream` depending on what it is you are trying to achieve.

So instead of

```
ConfigurationManager cm = new ConfigurationManager("src/clases/SpeechToText.config.xml");
```

You might use

```
ConfigurationManager cm = new ConfigurationManager("/clases/SpeechToText.config.xml");
```

And internally, you would need to use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream` to load it

Answer (score 4):

Files that you want to access at runtime should be accessed using the `getResourcesAsStream` method. For example:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("clases/SpeechToText.config.xml");
```

This will return an `InputStream` that you can use to read the file with.